# What is the difference between a node and a client?

Tags: nethereum

In ethereum, we do not usually interact with the network directly.

We interact with a node or a client.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are almost the same thing, but node is a server that's running a client. So, first of all you buy a Server that is strong enough to run a full node. Now, you install the client in the server. And then you can term the server running the client as a node. There are various client software providers such as Geth or Parity.

Comment: Ah. So there is a one to one correspondence between a node and a client. The exception is a rare exception where a server run 2 client.

Comment: Yes that could be true. But it is not really a good practice to have two clients running in same server. If the server somehow dies you lose two clients. Plus the requirements for the server could increase if we want to run two clients.